# KieBuilder.buildAll() doesn't works

Tags: drools

I'm trying to make this example working :
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-examples-api/kiefilesystem-example/src/main/java/org/drools/example/api/kiefilesystem/KieFileSystemExample.java

but when it tries to kb.buildAll(); (line 25) i get a kind of an error. I don't get any stack, any error message, but the debug stops as if i had a breakpoint, and in the debug window i have a FileNotFoundException

Any idea?

Comment: i tried to create it, but it doesn't change, still the same error

Comment: I would have to assume that you're running it from a location where that path is incorrect. Please update your question to describe how you are running the example.

Comment: fyi - The test shows how to run it: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/blob/master/drools-examples-api/kiefilesystem-example/src/test/java/org/drools/example/api/kiefilesystem/KieFileSystemExampleTest.java

Comment: Actually i should have missed some import or something, it's working now, thx